# Aquire a default value of a "select" HTML Input Element, via jQuery & JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I'm using a third-party jQuery plugin that gets the values, settings and preferences of a `<select>` element and replaces it with a custom widget.

How can I find out the default value of a `<select>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$("select option:selected");
```

To get the currently (or default) selected item. To get it's value, use

```
$("select option:selected").val();
```

Or

```
$("select").val()
```

If you want to be shorter/faster.

---

To get the select's original value, you need to store it in the element's data using the `.data()` function, as this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwskj/1/) shows.

When you want to retrieve the value, simply call `.data("originalValue")` on the select element (second `.each()` of the JSFiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        $(this).data("originalValue", $(this).val());
    });

    // Log data - will output "1"
    $("select").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).data("originalValue"));
    });
});
```

You need to run the first `.each()` call in the above code when your page loads to store the select box's original value. Do note that `originalValue` can be any identifier you like.

Comment: and if a Commando, like myself, change the initial selected value with some other option from the list, how can I fetch & select the first one ever selected, durring the page load instantiation of the objects and elementsŠ?

Comment: Is this a CSS pseudo-class or a jQuery specific item?  Trying to track down a link to `option:selected` and failing

Comment: @Jared This is a [jQuery specific](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector.

Comment: @Jared No problem! jQuery has several of it's own [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that make things a lot easier (`:input` for example).

Comment: There's no need to re-invent the wheel with `data` here - as my answer explains, finding the default values is easy enough without it.

Answer (score 5):

`<option>` elements have a property defined in DOM level 1 called `defaultSelected`.  This property will be set to true for any `<option>` element that has the `selected` attribute defined in the HTML when the element is parsed.

It should be fairly simple to use `filter` to get any default selected options:

```
var def = $("select > option").filter(function () { 
    return this.defaultSelected; 
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/9G3pR/**

- [defaultSelected property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: heavy stuff. this is the adequate one: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_defaultselected.asp ;)

Comment: @Commando: It looks pretty light to me ;-) Also, I avoid linking to w3schools wherever possible.  Take that particular page, for example and I quote, *"Note: If an option is selected by default, it is displayed first in the dropdown list."* - [That's just not right](http://w3fools.com).  Although MSDN doesn't always get it right either, at least the link I gave you in my answer also has a link to the W3C spec.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select option:selected').val();
```